# So I've made a Neural Network model for classifying dogs and cats with tensorflow keras, but it's accuracy isn't improving. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, networking, keras

So I'm fairly new to this stuff and I have written some code, written below, where the model I made doesn't seem to be classifying the cats and dogs. Basically the data is a large collection of cat and dog pictures, starting with 12500 cats, and then 12500 dogs in that order. I just can't seem to work out why this isn't working. I have tried adjusting weights and batch size, but nothing works. Any suggestions?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import random
import pickle

#cat: 1, dog: 0

training_data_path = '/Path/to/folder/containing/images'

IMG_SIZE = 100

training_data = []


def create_training_data():
    counter = 0
    for file in os.listdir(training_data_path):
        if 'cat' in str(file):
            label = 1
            img_path = os.path.join(training_data_path, file)
            array = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            new_array = cv2.resize(array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([new_array, label])
            print(counter)
            counter += 1
        else:
            label = 0
            img_path = os.path.join(training_data_path, file)
            print(img_path)
            print(label)
            array = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            new_array = cv2.resize(array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([new_array, label])
            print(counter)
            counter += 1

    random.shuffle(training_data)

    X = []
    y = []

    for point in training_data:
        X.append(point[0])
        y.append(point[1])

    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    pickle_out = open('X3.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()

    pickle_out = open('y3.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()



def NN_model():
    pickle_in = open('X3.pickle', 'rb')
    pickle_in_2 = open('y3.pickle', 'rb')
    batch_size = 1000
    X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    y = pickle.load(pickle_in_2)

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(X.shape[1:]))  

    f = keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)

    predictions = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(f)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)


    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X, y, epochs=5, batch_size=batch_size)


NN_model()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically a single dense layer with two units to classify your images.
This will not work, your network is simply too "simple" to be able to classify the images.

I suggest you have a look at the following tutorial:

[Keras Image Classification](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Snippet of their model below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, if I wanted to use a neural network model that wasn't convolutional, should I just alter the number of hidden layers, or does it have to be convolutional for this type of classification?

Comment: It should definately be convolutional, I mean in theory, if the pictures are simple enough it is probably possible without it but in your case they are not.


If you want to focus on a simple neural network for now, you can look at this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/binary-classification-tutorial-with-the-keras-deep-learning-library/

It is a simple classification problem which use numerical data instead of image as its input.